# Loop until connected to SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Sometimes when connecting to a remote SSH server I get `Connection Closed By *IP*; Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer.` But after trying one or two more times it connects properly.

This presents a problem with a few bash scripts I use to automatically upload my archived backups to the SSH server, like so;

```
export SSHPASS=$sshpassword
sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - root@$sshaddress << !
   cd $remotefolder
   put $backupfolder/Qt_$date.sql.gz
   bye
!
```

How can I have this part loop until it actually properly connects?

**UPDATE: (Solution)**

```
RETVAL=1
while [ $RETVAL -ne 0 ]
do
export SSHPASS=$sshpassword
sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - root@$sshaddress << !
   cd $remotefolder
   put $backupfolder/Qt_$date.tgz
   bye
!
RETVAL=$?
[ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && echo Success
[ $RETVAL -ne 0 ] && echo Failure
done
```

Comment: Solve the real problem, the "coudln't read packet: connection reset by peer".

Comment: Even if I did, I'd still like a way to verify if it's connected or not, and loop if it isn't... for all I know the server is rebooting or having network issues at the time the backup script is running from cron.

Comment: @natli, did you try to connect within a loop? e.g.: `i=0; until ssh $user@$ip || [ $i -eq 10 ]; do sleep 1; (( i++ )); done`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not a shell scripting expert, but I would check the return value of `sshpass` when it exits.

From `man ssh`:

```
ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or
with 255 if an error occurred.
```

From `man sshpath`:

> **Return Values**
>
> As with any other program, sshpass returns 0 on success. In case of
>   failure, the following return codes are used:
>
> 1. Invalid command line argument
> 2. Conflicting arguments given
> 3. General runtime error
> 4. Unrecognized response from ssh (parse error)
> 5. Invalid/incorrect password
> 6. Host public key is unknown. sshpass exits without confirming the new key.
>
> In addition, ssh might be complaining about a man in the middle
>   attack. This complaint does not go to the tty. In other words, even
>   with sshpass, the error message from ssh is printed to standard error.
>   In such a case ssh's return code is reported back. This is typically
>   an unimaginative (and non-informative) "255" for all error cases.

So try to run the command, and check its return value. If the return value was not `0` (for `SUCCESS`) then try again. Repeat using a `while` loop until you succeed.

Sidenote: why are you using `sshpass` instead of [public-key (passwordless) authentication?](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.55/htmldoc/Chapter8.html) It is more secure (you don't have to write down your password) and makes logging in via regular `ssh` as easy as `ssh username@host`.

There's [even an easy tool to set it up: `ssh-copy-id`.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
export SSHPASS=$sshpassword

sshpassFunc() {
    sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - root@$sshaddress << !
    cd $remotefolder
    put $backupfolder/Qt_$date.sql.gz
    bye
!
}

until sshpassFunc; do
    sleep 1
done
```

(not tested)

Comment: And now every process spawned by this knows your password in clear, because you exported it through an environment variable.  Please use passwordless pubkey exchange for these situations.